# get height and apply to each element failed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $.each($('.box'), function () {
     var heightOfBox = $(this).height();
     console.log(heightOfStory);
     $.each($('.line'), function () {
         $(this).css('height', heightOfBox + 'px');
     });
 });
```

I have a set of element which have different height, and I want to set it to another set. Above code failed because it get the last element's height instead of height of each of the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/vmxrca1d/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$.each($('.box'), function (i, val) {
     var heightOfBox = $(this).height();
     $(".line").eq(i).css('height', heightOfBox + 'px');

 });
```

```css
.box {
    background:red;
    width:10px;
    margin:10px;
}
.line {
    background:blue;
    width:10px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" style="height:10px;">1</div>
<div class="box" style="height:22px;">1</div>
<div class="box" style="height:40px;">1</div>
<div class="line">1</div>
<div class="line">1</div>
<div class="line">1</div>
```

use **eq()**

```
 $.each($('.box'), function (i, val) {
     $(".line").eq(i).css('height', $(this).height() + 'px');

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to set the corresponding element's height;

```
// Iterate over each of the element having box as class
$('.box').each(function (i, val) {
    $('.line').eq(i).height($(this).height());
    // Get the index of this element
    // Set the height of the corresponding element to the current element height
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vmxrca1d/4/)

Comment: why not just eq(idx)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$.each($('.box'), function (i,d) {
  var heightOfBox = $(d).height();
  console.log(heightOfBox);
$('.line:eq('+ i +')').css('height', heightOfBox + 'px');
});
```

[Working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vmxrca1d/8/)